# How to use jQuery autocomplete plugin with array of arrays in a js file as the source?

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have the published html output from an old, pc-based content management system. Basically it's a system that tech writers enter documentation "articles" into and then they click "Publish" and select the format and it publishes to one of word, pdf, html, etc. One of the files that it generates is a .js file that contains an array that contains many more arrays, in this format:

```
Page=new Array();

Page[0]=new Array("string", "string", "string", "string", "page_109.htm");

Page[1]=new Array("string", "string", "page_115.htm");

page[2]=new Array("string", "string", "string", "string", "string", "reference_201.htm");

var PageCount=3;
```

The above is a *very* shortened example of an actual file, but the structure is identical. Just many more pages.

I would like to use jquery autocomplete search (via a text field form) so that when the user types into a search field:

a. The autocomplete searches through the arrays in the included js file.
b. When an entry is clicked, the last index in the array, which contains the filename for the associated page, is loaded. (e.g., "109.htm")

Is this possible? Can anyone provide an example? I'm fairly new to javascript/jquery and was tasked with converting this old publishing system's HTML output (which uses a frameset) to responsive. The only thing left is to get the search working, and it would be *awesome* if I could get autocomplete working. I am open to using any plugin or built-in jquery function. The simpler the better.

Comment: The main problem is that the jQuery UI only accepts two data structures: an array of strings or an array of objects. Objects can contain  properties with name-value pairs. This doesn't really solve your problem. Since you create the JS file, i'd recommend changing it to a json file (you can use a .js extension since the mime is the same) and have a list of pages where each page has a list of key words.

Comment: Thanks Victor, but I actually don't create the js file that contains the arrays - the publishing system generates it based on the published content.

Comment: Hi @user172586 did the answer below  work for you?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with. There will be problems if more than one page share the same search word. Search for "apple" or "skeleton".

```js
        $( function() {

            Page=new Array();
            Page[0]=new Array("apples", "bananas", "cherries", "are", "page_109.htm");
            Page[1]=new Array("delicious", "but", "page_115.htm");
            Page[2]=new Array("vegetables", "vehicle", "sky", "skeleton", "sailboat", "reference_201.htm");

            var tags=[];
            for (i=0;i<Page.length;i++){
                for (n=0;n<Page[i].length-1;n++){
                    //ignore last item in list since it's the url
                    tags.push(Page[i][n]);
                }
            }
            $("#tags").autocomplete({
                source: tags,
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    console.log(getPage(ui.item.label));
                    alert(getPage(ui.item.label));
                }
            });
            function getPage(tag){
                for (i=0;i<Page.length;i++){
                    for (n=0;n<Page[i].length;n++){
                        //include the last item in the list. return it if there's a match
                        if (tag === Page[i][n]){
                            return Page[i][Page[i].length-1];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! This isn't exactly what I need but it gives me a great start!